# Tensor object has no attribute keras_shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras

While building a model using:

```
model = Model(inputs=[input_text], outputs=pred)
```

getting an error:

> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_shape'

The complete notebook that I tried can be found here...
https://github.com/shantanuo/pandas_examples/blob/master/tensorflow/tf_learn.ipynb

And the same code in plain text here...
https://gist.github.com/shantanuo/4e35baba144ee658e4dd4d1f87e19f3a

I will like to know why am I getting an error even if I am using the exact same code as shown in this blog:

https://towardsdatascience.com/transfer-learning-using-elmo-embedding-c4a7e415103c

The expected output - something like this:

> The model summary is:
>   _________________________________________________________________ Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
>   ================================================================= input_2 (InputLayer)         (None, 1)                 0
>   _________________________________________________________________ lambda_2 (Lambda)            (None, 1024)              0
>   _________________________________________________________________ dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 256)               262400
>   _________________________________________________________________ dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 257

I tried to upgrade tensorflow and keras but getting the same error:

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Comment: .... super cool bug there. Sounds like perfect code (at least the Keras model part). This error appears when you perform tensor operations outside layers, but I couldn't detect any, all your custom operations are inside a Lambda layer. So, I guess you've got a buggy/old version of "Keras" (this has nothing to do with tensorflow).

Comment: You can try to reset your kernel, though. Sometimes variables with similar names, typos, or weird vars get locked in memory with wrong states...this is rare, but it happens.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/54620221/10418812

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you change this:

```
from keras.models import Model
```

to this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
```

your code will be fine.

*** or ***

Change this:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input
```

to this:

```
from keras.layers import Input
```

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar issue when I changed my computer with a different tensorflow version.

What solved it for me was using `.shape` instead of `._keras_shape`

Depending on the version of tensorflow/keras and/or how you import them (`from keras`, `from tensorflow.keras` or `from tensorflow.python.keras`) it appears that the attributes names can differ.