# " ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found"- while Digit Recognition using CNN in Python using Keras

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, conv-neural-network

I am trying to write a simple character recolonization code using convolutional neural network in python on windows. I am following [this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/handwritten-digit-recognition-using-convolutional-neural-networks-python-keras/). But somehow I am having following error message. I could not find the appropriate reason of this error. It would be helpful for me if anyone can breakdown the error with probable solution.

```
    Using TensorFlow backend.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Mahin/PycharmProjects/characterRecognization/Learning/practice.py", line 2, in <module>
        from keras.datasets import mnist
      File "C:\Users\Mahin\PycharmProjects\characterRecognization\venv3.6\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
        from . import utils
      File "C:\Users\Mahin\PycharmProjects\characterRecognization\venv3.6\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
        from . import conv_utils
      File "C:\Users\Mahin\PycharmProjects\characterRecognization\venv3.6\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
        from .. import backend as K
      File "C:\Users\Mahin\PycharmProjects\characterRecognization\venv3.6\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
        from .tensorflow_backend import *
      File "C:\Users\Mahin\PycharmProjects\characterRecognization\venv3.6\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
        import tensorflow as tf
      File "C:\Users\Mahin\PycharmProjects\characterRecognization\venv3.6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
        from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
      File "C:\Users\Mahin\PycharmProjects\characterRecognization\venv3.6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
        from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
      File "C:\Users\Mahin\PycharmProjects\characterRecognization\venv3.6\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
        from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
      File "C:\Users\Mahin\PycharmProjects\characterRecognization\venv3.6\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
        from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `import tensorflow.keras...` or `import keras...`

Keras switched to `tensorflow.keras`, which is a part of tensorflow>=1.10.0.

Maybe it will help.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have installed CUDA, CUDNN, added them to your PATH variable, and if you have correct versions of them for your Tensorflow version (each Tensorflow version supports only range of CUDA versions), check for example [this tutorial](https://www.quantinsti.com/blog/install-tensorflow-gpu) for installation. 
Also, I guess you try to install it on windows (based on the DLL error), which is quite important to mention.