# Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined,

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, keras, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to define func(x) in order to use the genetic algs library here:
https://github.com/bobirdmi/genetic-algorithms/tree/master/examples
However, when I try and use `sga.init_random_population(population_size, params, interval)` the code complains of me using tf.Tensors as python bools.

However, I am only referencing one bool in the entire code (Elitism) so I have no idea why this error is even showing. Asked around others who used sga.init_... and my inputs/setup is fine. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Eric\eclipse-workspace\hw1\ga2.py", line 74, in <module>
    sga.init_random_population(population_size, params, interval)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\geneticalgs\real_ga.py", line 346, in init_random_population
    self._sort_population()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\geneticalgs\standard_ga.py", line 386, in _sort_population
    self.population.sort(key=lambda x: x.fitness_val, reverse=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 671, in __bool__
    raise TypeError("Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. "
TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.
```

code

```
import hw1
#import matplotlib
from geneticalgs import BinaryGA, RealGA, DiffusionGA, MigrationGA
#import numpy as np
#import csv
#import time
#import pickle
#import math
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from hw1 import x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test
from keras.losses import mean_squared_error
#import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
# GA standard settings
generation_num = 50
population_size = 16
elitism = True
selection = 'rank'
tournament_size = None # in case of tournament selection
mut_type = 1
mut_prob = 0.05
cross_type = 1
cross_prob = 0.95
optim = 'min' # minimize or maximize a fitness value? May be 'min' or 'max'.
interval = (-1, 1)
# Migration GA settings
period = 5
migrant_num = 3
cloning = True

def func(x):
    #dimensions of weights and biases
    #layer0weights = [10][23]
    #layer0biases = [10]
    #layer1weights = [10][20]
    #layer1biases = [20]
    #layer2weights = [1][20]
    #layer2biases = [1]
    #split up x for weights and biases
    lay0 = x[0:230]
    bias0 = x[230:240]
    lay1 = x[240:440]
    bias1 = x[440:460]
    lay2 = x[460:480]
    bias2 = x[480:481]
    #fit to the shape of the actual model
    lay0 = lay0.reshape(23,10)
    bias0 = bias0.reshape(10,)
    lay1 = lay1.reshape(10,20)
    bias1 = bias1.reshape(20,)
    lay2 = lay2.reshape(20,1)
    bias2 = bias2.reshape(1,)
    #set the newly shaped object to layers
    hw1.model.layers[0].set_weights([lay0, bias0])
    hw1.model.layers[1].set_weights([lay1, bias1])
    hw1.model.layers[2].set_weights([lay2, bias2])

    res = hw1.model.predict(x_train)
    error = mean_squared_error(res,y_train)
    return error

ga_model = Sequential()
ga_model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=23, activation='relu'))
ga_model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
ga_model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

sga = RealGA(func, optim=optim, elitism=elitism, selection=selection,
        mut_type=mut_type, mut_prob=mut_prob, 
        cross_type=cross_type, cross_prob=cross_prob)
params = 481

sga.init_random_population(population_size, params, interval)

optimal = sga.best_solution[0]

predict = func(optimal)
print(predict)
```

Comment: Usually when the program gives you an error, it indicates where that error occurs.  It might even show a 'traceback', a long list of function calls, ending with there error.  If  you don't provide us with that sort of information, we might just have close this as unclear.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/54620221/10418812

Comment: I edited to include the full traceback @hpaulj

Comment: Review the docs for `init_random_population`  What arguments does it take?  In one slot I think you gave it a tensor instead of a true/false parameter

Comment: The problem might be in one of the parameters for `sga`

Comment: It appears to have problems sorting a population, which apparently was an numpy array that was passed through your `func`.  Does `func` produce a `tf.Tensor`?

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow generates a computational graph of operations to be executed in an Tensorflow session.

`geneticalgs.RealGA.init_random_population` is an operation that uses the `numpy.random.uniform` to generate a numpy array. <sup>[1](https://github.com/bobirdmi/genetic-algorithms/blob/v1.0/geneticalgs/real_ga.py#L316)</sup>

The generated population being a Tensor object could mean maybe:

- `numpy.random.uniform` invoked in `geneticalgs.RealGA.init_random_population` was decorated to return Tensors
- `numpy.random.uniform` was added in the computation graph to be executed in a session.

I'll try executing the program eagerly by enabling eager execution. <sup>[2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.12.0/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L5356)</sup>

```
tf.enable_execution()
```

You can also in a way execute the parts that you care about eagerly.

```
size = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)
dim = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)
interval = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=(2,))

init_random_population = tf.py_func(
    sga.init_random_population, [size, dim, interval], [])

with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(
        init_random_population,
        {size: population_size, dim: params, interval: interval})
```