# ImportError :Failed to load the native Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pip, anaconda

**OS:** Windows 7

**Python version :** 3.5

**Cuda version :** 8.0

**Cudnn version :** 7.1

**GPU card version :** Qaudro 4000

I install Tensorflow using :

> pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade tensorflow-gpu

Tensorflow was installed in one of my Anaconda Environment.

But once I tried importing Tensorflow or keras(Which was also installed using pip on the same conda environment) is gave me a error:

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\HP\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Hope Someone would help me. Tried a lot of google search but couldn't solve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54620221/10418812

Comment: Nope ! It dint !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you have not added CUDA and CUDNN libraries to the PATH (based on the fact that it's missing DLL), add them to PATH so Tensorflow can find them.

Or maybe it is cause by incorrect version of CUDA and CUDNN, Tensorflow is quite picky about the version of both, so check if your CUDA and CUDNN versions are compatible with your Tensorflow version.

Comment: I have done that too. Do check i have mentioned the versions also .

Comment: Yeah, I read that and edited my answer after realizing you already have them.

Comment: Works now.! tried to install tensorflow with different environment.. Work fyn now