# 'Tensor' object is not callable using Keras and seq2seq model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I was following this [tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html), and I can compile and train my model like this:

```
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
encoder_embedding = Embedding(max_words, latent_dim)(encoder_inputs)
encoder_lstm, state_h, state_c = LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True)(encoder_embedding)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
decoder_embedding = Embedding(max_words, latent_dim)(decoder_inputs)
decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True)(decoder_embedding, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_outputs = Dense(decoder_target_data_size, activation='softmax')(decoder_lstm)

model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model.fit([X_train, Y_train], decoder_target_data, batch_size=128, epochs=100,validation_split=0.2, verbose=0)
```

But when I want to do the inference part

```
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)
decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(None,))
decoder_outputs, decoder_state_h = decoder_lstm(encoder_embedding, initial_state=decoder_state_input_h)
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
```

I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-c87095c25663> in <module>
      3 decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(None,), name="DecoderStateInput_1")
      4 
----> 5 decoder_outputs, decoder_state_h = decoder_lstm(encoder_embedding, initial_state=decoder_state_input_h)
      6 decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
      7 

TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not callable
```

I'm sure that is something about the Functional API, but I don't know how to solve it.

I'm using `keras-2.2.4` with `tensorflow-1.10.0`

If someone could help me I would be very thankful!

**EDIT**

I solved changing to this:

```
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)

decoder_hidden_state_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_cell_state_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_state_inputs = [decoder_hidden_state_inputs, decoder_cell_state_inputs]

decoder_lstm_outputs, decoder_hidden_state, decoder_cell_state = decoder_lstm(inputs=decoder_embedding(decoder_inputs),
                                                                              initial_state=decoder_state_inputs,
    )
decoder_state = [decoder_hidden_state, decoder_cell_state]

decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(inputs=decoder_lstm_outputs)

decoder_model = Model(
    inputs=[decoder_inputs] + decoder_state_inputs,
    outputs=[decoder_dense_outputs] + decoder_state,
)
```

Now, it's working fine!

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54620221/10418812

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning the Solution in this Section (even it is mentioned by Matias Aravena Gamboa in Question), for the benefit of the community.

Issue is resolved using the code mentioned below:

```
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)

decoder_hidden_state_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_cell_state_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_state_inputs = [decoder_hidden_state_inputs, decoder_cell_state_inputs]

decoder_lstm_outputs, decoder_hidden_state, decoder_cell_state = decoder_lstm(inputs=decoder_embedding(decoder_inputs),
                                                                              initial_state=decoder_state_inputs,
    )
decoder_state = [decoder_hidden_state, decoder_cell_state]

decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(inputs=decoder_lstm_outputs)

decoder_model = Model(
    inputs=[decoder_inputs] + decoder_state_inputs,
    outputs=[decoder_dense_outputs] + decoder_state,
)
```